# Jumping around to certain spots in script

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to make a script jump to a specific spot like :GOTO in command prompt? I wanted to make the script jump to the beginning when it is ended.

```
$tag1 = Read-Host 'Enter tag #'

cls

sc.exe \\$tag1 start RemoteRegistry

cls

Start-Sleep -s 2

cls

systeminfo /S $tag1 | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"System Boot Time" /C:"System Up Time";


Get-EventLog system -computername $tag1 -InstanceId 2147489657 -Newest 10 | ft EventID,TimeWritten,MachineName -AutoSize

Pause
```

Comment: Goto is not evil. There are only evil programmers.

Comment: Real world example: 1500-line install script now needs uninstall. Several hundred lines of presets, constants, functions and current-state scanning are the same -- at which point a simple `if($mode -eq "u") goto Uninstall` would be awfully damned handy right now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's and example using your script:

```
$GetInfo = {
  $tag1 = Read-Host 'Enter tag # or Q to quit'
  if ($tag1 -eq 'Q'){Return}
  cls
  sc.exe \\$tag1 start RemoteRegistry
  cls
  Start-Sleep -s 2
  cls
  systeminfo /S $tag1 | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"System Boot Time" /C:"System Up Time"
  Get-EventLog system -computername $tag1 -InstanceId 2147489657 -Newest 10 |
    ft EventID,TimeWritten,MachineName -AutoSize
  .$GetInfo
 }

&$GetInfo
```

Use . instead of & inside the script block to prevent it from walking up the call stack.

Putting code into script blocks to be called later from arbitrary points in the script (emulating a GoTo) is functionally the same as using a function, and script block used in this manner are sometimes referred to as "anonymous functions".

Comment: So to get the systeminfo command and the Get-EventLog command to run at the same time I just have to put it on different lines without using the ; symbol ?

Comment: Pretty much. Put each one in it's own script block, assigned to it's own variable, and the dot-source that variable to run it.

Comment: How does the Q know to quit? Or am I not seeing something?

Comment: The `systeminfo` line can (and should) be replaced with a WMI query.

Comment: This line: if ($tag1 -eq 'Q'){Return} causes the exit from the script block when the user enters 'Q' to quit.

Comment: The Return tells it to hit the Return key and exit?

Comment: The Return keyword exits the current scope, which can be a function, script, or script block. See Get-Help About_Return

Comment: Ah okay. Is there a way in powershell to color code certain results rather than making the entire output one color?

Comment: See get-help write-host for creating colorized console output. You should probably start new questions rather than keep adding comments to this one for different questions.

Comment: @alroc - you're probably right about the WMI, but that's not addressing the question being asked IMHO.

Comment: Good technique for the tool bag. But for this case: yuck!

Answer (score 9):

There's no `goto` functionality in PowerShell. Wrap the block of commands in a loop or something.

Or you can assign list of commands to a variable, and then execute them with `&$varname`. It's still not goto, though.

```
$commands = {

    Write-Host "do some work"

    $again = Read-Host "again?"
    if ($again -eq "y"){
        &$commands
    } else {
        Write-Host "end"    
    }
}

&$commands
```

Comment: I updated the OP with my script. Not sure how I combine that with what you have ..

Comment: This requires pretty advanced knowledge to use first class script blocks. It's not obvious or clear in intent that it's a loop. And it will consume resources until it hits the dynamic call depth limit, and then lock up and throw an exception at some unpredictable time and stop looping. Are you sure you prefer this design to `:start          goto start`  ?

Comment: I miss goto's, they are not just for looping. I used them a lot for redirecting depending certain errors or results without having to leave the current method. I also agree with @TessellatingHeckler, the plain English of "GoTo" seems more obvious than this new architecture. Being more obvious can reduce dev time when trying to decipher a script that someone else wrote; who may, or may not be, at a different skill level.

Answer (score 3):

Another variation on the script with some ideas taken from @mjolinor. I also switched away from using `systeminfo` because at least on my computer, it's **much** slower than using the applicable WMI query.

```
while (1) {
    $tag1 = Read-Host 'Enter tag # or Q to quit'
    if ($tag1 -eq "Q") {
        break;
    }
    sc.exe \\$tag1 start RemoteRegistry;
    start-sleep -seconds 2
    $OSInfo = get-wmiobject -class win32_operatingsystem -computername $tag1;
    $OSInfo | Format-Table -Property @{Name="OS Name";Expression={$_.Caption}},@{Name="System Boot Time";Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastBootUpTime)}},@{Name="System Uptime (Days)";Expression={[math]::Round((New-TimeSpan -Start $_.converttodatetime($_.LastBootUpTime)|select-object -expandproperty totaldays),2)}} -AutoSize;
    Get-EventLog system -computername $tag1 -InstanceId 2147489657 -Newest 10 | format-table EventID,TimeWritten,MachineName -AutoSize
}
```

I'm not certain that WMI needs remote registry, so you might be able to eliminate the `sc.exe` line and `sleep` altogether. Unless you need it for something else.

Comment: Interesting way of doing that. A lot more code as well. Will have to look through that more.

Comment: Run it and see what you get. It may appear to be "more code" (which is rarely a valuable metric, BTW), but the `get-wmiobject` method should be faster than `systeminfo` and the end result is formatted (the formatting taking up a lot of that "extra" code).

Comment: What if the system is 64bit? I see it says win32 there?

Comment: It's just the name of the WMI class, it's part of the Win32 API. It works identically on all modern versions of Windows. Again, run it and see for yourself.

Comment: It does work faster. Is this pulling the OS Name and system boot time from a different location?

Comment: I don't know how `systeminfo` works, so I can't say. I do know that it pulls a lot more data. WMI (and in current OSes, CIM) is the more accepted practice these days, especially within PowerShell.